# Swig + tcl + c++ (memory managment)

Tags: c++, tcl, swig

I have a procedure in tcl that again call a c++ method using interface created by swig. The procedure returns a list of pointers. I checked ownership for a single element in the List in tcl using

```
[lindex $listname 0] cget -thisown
```

it returns 0 instead of 1.

Comment: What is your Q exacty? We are not mind readers to read the Q that is in your mind.

Comment: why I am getting 0 instead of 1?

Comment: Because it's not owned, as per spec. Why were you expecting it to be owned? What problem is this causing for you?

Comment: Actually I am validating arguments passed to a tcl procedure. If argument is a single pointer validation is passed, but if argument is a list of valid pointers this validation fails. And this failure takes place when the list that is passed, is being returned by any other procedure in tcl.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [SWIG documentation on memory management](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Tcl.html#Tcl_nn31), pointers aren't owned by (the SWIG binding to) Tcl by default. If SWIG has got it wrong, use the `-acquire`/`-disown` operations to correct it. For example:

```
[lindex $listname 0] -acquire
```

Be careful! Getting memory management wrong will lead to confusing crashes or memory leaks.